# Breaking change for google-api-python-client 1.9.3 - AttributeError: module 'google.api_core' has no attribute 'gapic_v1'

Tags: python, api, github, google-cloud-platform

Is anyone else getting the above?

I can't for the life of me figure out why it's complaining about the google.api.core module. This was working for me last week, but since updating the google-api-python-client it's now not, and I'm struggling to get back to a working version.

Pip freeze, as requested:

```
asgiref==3.2.7
astroid==2.3.3
cachetools==3.1.1
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
colorama==0.4.1
Django==3.0.6
django-crispy-forms==1.9.0
django-formtools==2.2
Flask==1.1.1
google-api-core==1.21.0
google-api-python-client==1.9.3
google-auth==1.18.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-cloud==0.34.0
google-cloud-core==1.1.0
google-cloud-error-reporting==0.33.0
google-cloud-firestore==1.6.2
google-cloud-kms==1.3.0
google-cloud-logging==1.14.0
google-cloud-pubsub==1.1.0
google-cloud-secret-manager==0.2.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.6.0
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.3
grpcio==1.27.2
httplib2==0.14.0
idna==2.8
isort==4.3.21
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.3
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
oauth2client==4.1.3
oauthlib==3.1.0
protobuf==3.12.2
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.7
PyJWT==1.7.1
pylint==2.4.4
pytz==2019.3
PyYAML==5.3.1
requests==2.22.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.0
six==1.13.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
twilio==6.35.5
uritemplate==3.0.0
urllib3==1.25.7
Werkzeug==0.16.0
wrapt==1.11.2
```

Comment: Can you provide a full `requirements.txt` or a `pip freeze` of the environment?

Comment: @DustinIngram - Please see the edited OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google-api-core 1.17.0 suffers from [another regression](https://github.com/googleapis/python-api-core/issues/25) (fixed in the most recent version) that breaks the streaming pull, thus the users that use that feature should instead temporarily pin google-api-core to an even older version, e.g. 1.16.0. For More detailed please refer to [link](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/issues/115).

Comment: Thanks! Reverting to 1.16.0 worked for me in the end.